# manage my margin according to screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I manage left margin depending to screen sizes. Actually I have a form that slides from left side by clicking a button. But I cant set actual left margin to this form.

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $( window ).resize(function() { 

        var sh =  $( window ).width();   
        if(sh > "1300" && sh < "1350")
        {      
         document.getElementById("pay").style.marginLeft="0%";
         document.getElementById("feedback1").style.marginLeft="0%";
        }
        else if(sh > "1350" && sh < "1400")
        {         
         document.getElementById("pay").style.marginLeft="-7%";
         document.getElementById("feedback1").style.marginLeft="-7%";
        }
        else if(sh > "1200" && sh < "1300")
        {         
         document.getElementById("pay").style.marginLeft="7%";
         document.getElementById("feedback1").style.marginLeft="7%";
        }
        else if(sh > "950" && sh < "1200")
        { 
         document.getElementById("pay").style.marginLeft="12%";
         document.getElementById("feedback1").style.marginLeft="12%";
        }
        else if(sh > "1400" && sh < "1600")
        {  

         document.getElementById("pay").style.marginLeft="-7%";
         document.getElementById("feedback1").style.marginLeft="-7%";
        }
        else if(sh > "1600" && sh < "1900")
        {          
         document.getElementById("pay").style.marginLeft="-25%";
         document.getElementById("feedback1").style.marginLeft="-25%";
        }
       });
```

But its not working properly for different screen sizes. Can anyone give me proper suggestion?

Comment: Use CSS3 media queries, so depending upon the browser resolution you can modify the CSS attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should used CSS media queries instead of javascript to solve your problem.

Here is an example:

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />
```

Or inline styles:

```
<style>
    @media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 800px) {
      #pay{
         margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
</style>
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

Even tho it's not what you're trying to do there but you could use CSS3 actions 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp
here's a tutorial

Comment: Check out w3fools.com